# Assign home page in a lightning app in managed package

Tags: lightning, managed-package

I have managed package with its own app. I want to assign a lightning page as the home page of that app.

How can we set it up?

Comment: You can do so with [Spring '19](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_home_assign_app.htm), is that not working for you?

Comment: i can do it if i am to set it up in client org. Can i have it setup such that the app always default this page on install. I need to go and set it up in client org to make that page as the default home page. Or am i missing something?

Comment: I am not too sure how it will work in managed package scenario. The best bet here is to try it out. See if you set the home page as default in the app in your managed package and if it retains it after you install it. I would imagine it will.

Comment: I couldnt get it working with managed package, so that was the reason for the question.

Comment: You may like to edit your question to reflect that you have already tried the Spring '19 feature and still does not work. If someone knows other ways, may be able to help you then